# How to group data and return the rest fields?

Tags: mongodb, aggregate, aggregation

I want to filter the `report` field, where `m_name = "ABC"`, and group it back.
Here's my sample data:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("63f82b8619e8f81b7009d2c3"),
    "type" : "test"
    "created_at" : date
    "created_by" : "admin",
    "report" : [
        {
            "name" : "Day 3",
            "date" : date
            "m_name" : "ABC",
            "created_by" : "admin",
            "created_at" :date
        },
        {
            "name" : "Day 2",
            "date" :date,
            "created_by" : "admin",
            "m_name" : "ABC",
            "created_at" : date
        },
        {
            "name" : "test",
            "date" : date
            "m_name": "123"
            "created_by" : "admin",
            "created_at" : date,
        },
    ],
   ... 20 fields

}
```

Here's my pipeline:

```
      .aggregate([ 
       {
          $unwind: "report",
        },
        {
          $match: {
            "report.m_name": "ABC",
          },
        },
        {
          $group: {
            _id: "$_id",
            report: {
              $push: "$report",
            },
            
          },
        },
       ])
```

If do like this, output only have `_id` and `report`, how to return all the rest fields?
I've tried the $$ROOT, but it embedded in a object, I want the output like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("63f82b8619e8f81b7009d2c3"),
    "type" : "test"
    "created_at" : date
    "created_by" : "admin",
    "report" : [
        {
            "name" : "Day 3",
            "date" : date
            "m_name" : "ABC",
            "created_by" : "admin",
            "created_at" :date
        },
        {
            "name" : "Day 2",
            "date" :date,
            "created_by" : "admin",
            "m_name" : "ABC",
            "created_at" : date
        },
    ],
   ... 20 fields

}
```

I know `project` (type: {$first: "$type"},) will do, but there are 20 fields, any other simpler way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$filter`:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$set: {
      report: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$report",
          cond: {$eq: ["$$this.m_name", "ABC"]}
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/1xfJe3mcpaD)

Comment: this result is definitely what i want, pipeline is short too, thank you so much!